# Customized node edit page

Tags: views, nodes

How to customized the node edit page?
i was created one cart site for online education.
here i need one button to while edit the  node one of the content type?
how to create an button in node edit page?
how to add function for specific function for that button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a button to the node form, with a submit function for that button, using hook_form_alter()

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  $content_type = 'page'; // change as necessary
  if($form_id == $content_type . '_node_form')
  {
    $form['actions']['my_button'] = array
    (
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Do something'),
      '#submit' => array('my_submit_function'),
    );
  }
}

function my_submit_function($form, &$form_state)
{
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: these changes are implemented in node.tpl.php file rigth?

Comment: @vigneshrajkumar wrong, this code needs to go inside **template.php** located in `/sites/all/themes/[yourtheme]` folder if you're on D7. If on D8 it would be inside **yourtheme.theme** file.

Comment: @vigneshrajkumar you also need to replace the word `hook` with the name of your theme

Comment: You can also create a custom module ([Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules) & [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules)) to make this theme independant. Create the `info file` as per the tutorial and add above hook in the `.module` file.